# Value in array is changed when I change a value in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops

I have a problem where I'm having two arrays. Whenever I'm changing a value in one array with the code shown below, the other array do also get the same change which is not intended. If i copy and paste the code below in the javascript console in my browser I get the problem that originalArray is changed after I called ConvertDataArrayToLocationArray(dataArray)

```js
let originalArray = [
  {
    "date": "2018-11-16",
    "type": "Entertainment",
    "location": "Oslo",
    "amount": 1024
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-16",
    "type": "Food",
    "location": "Oslo",
    "amount": 170
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-17",
    "type": "Food",
    "location": "Fredrikstad",
    "amount": 99
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-18",
    "type": "Food",
    "location": "Halden",
    "amount": 29
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-19",
    "type": "Entertainment",
    "location": "Oslo",
    "amount": 34
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-20",
    "type": "Entertainment",
    "location": "Oslo",
    "amount": 15
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-20",
    "type": "Food",
    "location": "Fredrikstad",
    "amount": 80
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-23",
    "type": "Transportation",
    "location": "Stavanger",
    "amount": 95
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-28",
    "type": "Entertainment",
    "location": "Oslo",
    "amount": 1024
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-29",
    "type": "Food",
    "location": "Oslo",
    "amount": 117.39
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-30",
    "type": "Transportation",
    "location": "Fredrikstad",
    "amount": 29
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-12-2",
    "type": "Transportation",
    "location": "Stavanger",
    "amount": 184
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-12-3",
    "type": "Entertainment",
    "location": "Oslo",
    "amount": 34
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-12-4",
    "type": "Food",
    "location": "Oslo",
    "amount": 162
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-12-4",
    "type": "Food",
    "location": "Fredrikstad",
    "amount": 231
  }
];

function ConvertDataArrayToLocationArray(dataArray) {

    let newArray = [];
    console.log("First dataArray[0].amount is the correct value. ");
    console.log(dataArray[0].amount);

    for(let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {

        let existed = false;

        for(let j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {

            if(dataArray[i].location === newArray[j].location) {

                newArray[j].amount = (newArray[j].amount + dataArray[i].amount);

                existed = true;

            }
        }


        if(!existed) {
            newArray.push(dataArray[i]); 

        }
    }

    console.log("Why is this dataArray[0].amount suddenly different?");
    console.log(dataArray[0].amount); 
    return newArray; 

}

let a = ConvertDataArrayToLocationArray(originalArray);
```

My excepted outcome is that the variable called originalArray stays unchanged and I get a new array from the return value of ConvertDataArrayToLocationArray(dataArray).

Comment: try `console.log(originalArray[0].amount); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inserting an item into `newArray`, you are passing a reference to the object.

So, any changes made to the item in new copied array `newArray` are reflected in the original array, and vice versa.

To prevent this, instead of passing a reference, pass a copy of the object.

```
newArray.push({...dataArray[i]});
```

I'm using ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make a copy. We also have [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method and several others ways to clone an object.

For your data, these would be enough because all properties are primitives. If there are object properties you have to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataArray[i]))` or other [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/2924577).

Answer (score 1):

make a deep copy using : 
`const dataArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));` :

```js
let originalArray = [
  {
    date: "2018-11-16",
    type: "Entertainment",
    location: "Oslo",
    amount: 1024
  },
  {
    date: "2018-11-16",
    type: "Food",
    location: "Oslo",
    amount: 170
  },
  {
    date: "2018-11-17",
    type: "Food",
    location: "Fredrikstad",
    amount: 99
  },
  {
    date: "2018-11-18",
    type: "Food",
    location: "Halden",
    amount: 29
  },
  {
    date: "2018-11-19",
    type: "Entertainment",
    location: "Oslo",
    amount: 34
  },
  {
    date: "2018-11-20",
    type: "Entertainment",
    location: "Oslo",
    amount: 15
  },
  {
    date: "2018-11-20",
    type: "Food",
    location: "Fredrikstad",
    amount: 80
  },
  {
    date: "2018-11-23",
    type: "Transportation",
    location: "Stavanger",
    amount: 95
  },
  {
    date: "2018-11-28",
    type: "Entertainment",
    location: "Oslo",
    amount: 1024
  },
  {
    date: "2018-11-29",
    type: "Food",
    location: "Oslo",
    amount: 117.39
  },
  {
    date: "2018-11-30",
    type: "Transportation",
    location: "Fredrikstad",
    amount: 29
  },
  {
    date: "2018-12-2",
    type: "Transportation",
    location: "Stavanger",
    amount: 184
  },
  {
    date: "2018-12-3",
    type: "Entertainment",
    location: "Oslo",
    amount: 34
  },
  {
    date: "2018-12-4",
    type: "Food",
    location: "Oslo",
    amount: 162
  },
  {
    date: "2018-12-4",
    type: "Food",
    location: "Fredrikstad",
    amount: 231
  }
];

function ConvertDataArrayToLocationArray(arr) {
  const dataArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    let existed = false;

    for (let j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++) {
      if (dataArray[i].location === newArray[j].location) {
        newArray[j].amount = newArray[j].amount + 10;

        existed = true;
      }
    }

    if (!existed) {
      newArray.push(dataArray[i]);
    }
  }

  return newArray;
}

let a = ConvertDataArrayToLocationArray(originalArray);

console.log(originalArray[0]);
console.log(a[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Do you have any idea why this happened?